# Detect undisposed instances of a class in a running process?

Tags: .net, debugging, windbg

I have an IIS Application, that runs in w3wp.exe. I'm not 100% sure if one of my classes is disposed and increases memory footprint over time (just looking at Memory usage in Task Manager isn't that reliable).

Is there a simple way to take a memory dump (that's easy in Win2008, through Task Manager), load it into WinDbg or Visual Studio and just ask "How many instances of Foo.Bar are in this memory dump?"

I know I could/should use a Memory Profiler, but I don't have that option right now as it's a production system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to take a memory
>   dump (that's easy in Win2008, through
>   Task Manager), load it into WinDbg or
>   Visual Studio and just ask "How many
>   instances of Foo.Bar are in this
>   memory dump?

You can use [Proc Dump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900) to get the memory dump.

In WinDbg `!dumpheap –stat` will give you the allocation by type

If you use `!dumpheap -type Foo.Bar` you should get just the Classes that start with Foo.Bar

see  [SOS.dll (SOS Debugging Extension)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) for more information

Answer (score 1):

You can use a decorator class which has a finalizer and dispose method and alerts you on a missed dispose. So if your class is like this:

```
public class CustomerTracker
{
   public bool IsNew() {...}
}
```

Then define an interface and make the client code use it:

```
public interface ICustomerTracker
{
   public bool IsNew();
}
```

Define a decorator and use it where you create any of these objects:

```
public class CustomerTrackerMemDecorator : ICustomerTracker
{
   ICustomrTracker tracker;

    CustomerTrackerMemDecorator (ICustomrTracker tracker)
    {
            this.tracker = tracker;
    }

    public bool IsNew() { return tracker.IsNew(); }

    ~CustomerTrackerMemDecorator
    {
            Debug.Assert("Missed dispose found!");
    }

    public override Dispose()
    {
            tracker.Dispose();
            GC.SupressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Then where ever you have:

CustomerTracker tracker= new CustomerTracker();

replace it with

ICustomerTracker tracker = new CustomerTrackerMemDecorator(new CustomerTracker());